# Error-handling in asynch functions

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, web-scraping, error-handling

I want to throw an error into the console if the following function doesn't work for any reason. It's getting some data from a website, writing them into a mongoDB. 
If for example the insert into mongoDB or the scraping fails I want to get an error message in the console. I have no idea how to archive proper error-handling with nodejs (0 clue about promises and stuff).

```
artikel.getData(async () => { for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfArticles.length; i++){
    await scrape(i).then((price) => {

        console.log('Data ' + arrayOfArticles[i] + ': ' + received);

        //Connect to DB
        MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true}, function(err, db) {
            if (err) throw err;
            let dbo = db.db("testDB");
            let insertPart = {
                name: arrayOfArticles[i],
                site: dealer,
                price: price
            };


            dbo.collection("testcollection").insertOne(insertPart, function(err, res) {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log(divide);
            console.log("Document inserted");
            console.log(divide);
            db.close();
            }); 
        });
    });
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not write DB connection code inside the loop or inside API. It should be in some config file.

You don't need to write `.then` with await, use try-catch for error handling.

```
artikel.getData(() => {
    MongoClient.connect(url, {
        useNewUrlParser: true
    }, async function (err, db) {
        for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfArticles.length; i++) {
            try {
                const price = await scrape(i);
                //Connect to DB
                if (err) throw err;
                let dbo = db.db("testDB");
                let insertPart = {
                    name: arrayOfArticles[i],
                    site: dealer,
                    price: price
                };

                dbo.collection("testcollection").insertOne(insertPart, function (err, res) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        throw err
                    };
                    console.log(divide);
                    console.log("Document inserted");
                    console.log(divide);
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
        db.close();
    });
});
```

Comment: this really helped me out a lot